# How should I subclass NSWindow initialization in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

i want to create a subclass of `NSWindow`.  this subclass needs to initialize some member variables before they are used.  what is the best way to capture initialization in objective c?  what i find is that `init` rarely gets called in a way that allows me to do this.  `NSWindow` has a couple of initialization vectors that i would need to override.  do i need to override each of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each class should have one so-called designated initializer. This is the init method that all other init methods call. That's the one to override. The documentation usually tells you which one the designated initializer is. In the case of `NSWindow`, it is:

`initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:`

> This method is the designated initializer for the NSWindow class.

In addition to the designated initializer, you should also override `-initWithCoder:` if the class you subclass implements the `NSCoding` protocol. `-initWithCoder:` is the initializer that is used when an instance is instantiated from an archive (such as a NIB file).

See [The Designated Initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html) in Apple's "The Objective-C Programming Language".

Comment: While it's true that initWithCoder: is a second designated initializer, NSWindows created with IB aren't initialized with initWithCoder:. Instances of 'Custom View' and the blue cube generic object fall into the same boat. Most other objects are indeed initialized with initWithCoder: when loaded from a NIB file.

Comment: The designated initializer link is dead. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html)'s the new one.

Comment: In the macOS 10.12 SDK documentation, in NSWindow, the designated initializer is not stated.  As always, when Apple documentation is incomplete, check the header file!  Indeed, the method noted above is marked as NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER in NSWindow.h.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried overriding the designated initialiser

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)deferCreation screen:(NSScreen *)screen
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: In the macOS 10.12 SDK, the designated initializer for NSWindow is not the one stated here by Abizem but is the one stated by Ole.  Note the lack of the last parameter, `screen:`.

Comment: that practically invisible `screen:` param tho... thanks @JerryKrinock, saved me some frustration